# Where is the error in "He ate nothing since yesterday"?

Tags: present-perfect

In the following sentence, where is the error?

> He ate nothing since yesterday.

The book offer these choices:

> (1) He ate
>   (2) nothing
>   (3) since yesterday.
>   (4) No error

It seems to me "no error," but the book I am reading states it has an error at the first part.

Perhaps "He had eaten" should be used instead?

Comment: As per the comments on all of your other questions, please provide what **you** think is wrong with the answer. Proofreading questions are off-topic on ELL.

Answer (score 5):

*He ate* should be *he has eaten*. The present perfect should be used because the sentence describes the situation that began in the past and continues up to the present time.